# Mist freezes on Linux Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: mist

Mist (0.7.2) freezes on Linux Ubuntu 15.10

Mist (0.7.2) freezes and just displays a white rectangular box especially when I stop it and restart it. This is white screen before the Mist browser even launches. Initially I could see the downloading blockchain splash screen so it might not be related to a video or graphics issue. Not sure.

Even if I kill the processes and restart Mist it remains frozen.

If I log out of Ubuntu and back in the problem remains.

The only thing that seems to fix it is restarting the computer.

Any advice?

Comment: Generally useful to include version/s of Mist that was tried.

Comment: Updated the question. Mist 0.7.2. You think downgrading to an earlier version would solve the issue? Any version  in particular being stable?

Comment: @eth I tried closing all Ethereum processes, downloading 0.6.2 and clicked it. It seems to run and just take off where 0.7.2 ended. ethereum.stackexchange.com is so useful and cool : ) Well, I will see how it goes. Will report if I get stuck somewhere again.

Comment: This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If the answers from the duplicates don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and flag this for re-opening. Thanks!

Comment: I rejoiced too early. First it worked with Mist 0.6.2 but then it started to behave oddly again. What's up with these freezing issues when downloading the blockchain initially?

Comment: Send a link to the alleged duplicate question, I don't think it's the same necessarily. At @5chdn Ok, found it. Hmm.. Not sure if it's the same. This is white screen before the Mist browser even launches. Plus it did not occur at first, so I could see the blockchain downloading splash screen initially.

Comment: Please use the edit button to add more details to your question. Try to avoid lots of comments.